# IOS - image is not horizontally covering the full width of the screen

Tags: ios, iphone, uistoryboard, uistackview

hello I am new to IOS and I am trying to learn the StackViews. I have added the image on the screen but the problem is first it is not fully covering the screen vertically and also not on the top in the device, meaning leaving some space or margin on top and on left and right side. [image]

you can see in the attached image that there are space around left and right side and also on the top. If you need more information regarding what Properties I set in the right attribute selector please let me know,I'll update my question

Answer (score 0):

Because you're connecting to the `layout margins`.

Try holding <kbd>option</kbd> when you're adding your constraint that triggers `margins` vs `borders`

Comment: sorry could you explain a bit more in detail. I don't understand it. @Islam Q.

Answer (score 0):

When applying constraints to stackview. uncheck Constraint to margin. And then apply constraints

[image]

[image]

The top margin is default for notification area. To hide this area: Go to size inspector.

[image]

Change y from 20 to zero. and update constraint by selecting the stackview.

[image]